# Adding Realm objc files inside own static framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, realm, objective-c-runtime

I am creating framework in ObjC first time.

- I want to store data inside realm dynamically. i.e. I have JSON for schema and data, and want to create classes, it's properties, objects, etc dynamically.
- I have gone through their example code, they have provided `DynamicTests.m` where they have created data dynamically but I don't get it correctly.

Now I have few concerns and doubts.

1. What files/Folders should I include to create realm database at runtime? (ie. script folder, configuration Folder, swift folder, core folder?).
2. How to create dynamic schema and classes with their properties?
3. Is there any limitation or precaution that I should keep in my mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good questions!

> 1. What files/Folders should I include to create realm database at runtime? (ie. script folder, configuration Folder, swift folder, core folder?).

Realm is no different than any other framework in this regard. When building a static framework that depends on another static framework, statically link the dependent framework all you'll be all set. No additional files are required.

> 2. How to create dynamic schema and classes with their properties?

By importing the `Realm.Dynamic` module, you can construct `RLMProperty` , `RLMObjectSchema` and finally `RLMSchema` instances which you can then pass in to `RLMRealmConfiguration.customSchema`. Also make sure to set the `RLMRealmConfiguration.dynamic` property to `YES`.

> 3. Is there any limitation or precaution that I should keep in my mind?

The dynamic APIs are a bit verbose and not included in the HTML API documentation, so you're using Realm in "expert" mode ;). That being said, the Realm team is happy to help with any issues you might encounter (I work at Realm).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late response. I have changed my approach to use realm now. I have now created model in which user have to add realm framework, create and give realm object and Its related classes to my framework for mapping.